# Porque usamos o ContainerInterface ao injetar o @service_container como argumento?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, symfony-2

No arquivo `services.yml` tenho o seguinte serviço configurado:

```
services:
    api.response_factory:
        class: AppBundle\Api\ResponseFactory
        arguments: ['@service_container']
```

Na classe `ResponseFactory` tenho o método construtor que recebe o argumento:

```
namespace AppBundle\Api;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

public function __construct(Container $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Repare que o argumento `container` é do tipo `ContainerInterface`.

Se é apenas uma interface, como é possível o código abaixo funcionar?

```
$this->container->get('router')->generate('ROTA_A');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método diz que aceita objetos cuja classe *implementa* a interface `ContainerInterface`. Não significa que você está recebendo uma instância de uma interface – isso seria impossível.

No caso do código acima, você está recebendo uma instância da classe `Container` (que, por sua vez, implementa a interface `ContainerInterface`). É por isso que, a partir do container, você consegue pegar o serviço `router` e, assim, gerar a rota desejada.

Outra coisa: evite injetar os containers de serviço em outros serviços; prefira injetar serviços individuais, assim seu código fica mais limpo e conciso.

Por exemplo, se você quiser injetar apenas o serviço `router` (que é o mesmo argumento quando você usa o método `get` do container), crie sua definição de serviço da seguinte forma:

```
services:
    api.response_factory:
        class: AppBundle\Api\ResponseFactory
        arguments: ['@router']
```

E então altere o construtor para receber um objeto que implementa a classe `RouterInterface`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Api;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class ResponseFactory
{
    /** @var RouterInterface $router */
    protected $router;

    /**
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
}
```

Você pode ver todos os serviços disponíveis na sua aplicação (inclusive os que você criou) por meio do comando `app/console container:debug` (ou `bin/console debug:container` no caso de Symfony 3 para cima).

Comment: Rodrigo, como assim injetar serviços individuais? No meu serviço preciso gerar uma rota e preciso do container para isso, como seria uma boa prática para isso?

Comment: Alterei a resposta para responder à sua pergunta. :)

Comment: Admiro quem programa usando Symfony :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters meu framework preferido desde sempre :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isso foi um elogio? kkk! Symfony não é solução para tudo mas serve muito bem para os projetos que estou envolvido no momento!

Comment: @FilipeMoraes sim. O Framework é complexo, mas é bem feito. Apesar de preferir o código-fonte (a beleza do código) do Laravel, eu acho que o Symfony é muito bem estruturado. Inclusive o Laravel tem um parte que usa o HttpFoundation do Symfony. Então querendo ou não, eu acabo usando Symfony :D